# I cannot read a file using the context manager (with)

Tags: python, with-statement

Using the following code:

```
with open("sd1file.txt",'r') as testfile:
    file_contents = testfile.read
    print (file_contents)
```

I get this error

```
<built-in method read of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x02EEB4B0>
```

I can use 
`file = open(testfile,'r')` etc with out problems
i.e. the file exists and is accessible i.e. I can read and write to it.

Is there some module that I need to import or something?

Comment: You should read your log. This is not an error message. You assign `testfile.read`  to the variable. `testfile.read` is a built-in method. You print the value of `file_contents`. After reading your output and noticing that it's not an error but a stringified method, you should see the problem that you don't call the method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not calling the method

```
file_contents = testfile.read()
```

Comment: Answered in the dupe.

Comment: Actually,I did not get the answer by Makato. Now I see that testfile is not the file or data but a method for reading (or writing to) the file. Or I could have copied the example script more carefully.

Comment: @John_rb You can mark as a correct answer if you think it solved your question